# PHP - How would you catch the line at which an error is thrown when decoding a json?

Tags: php, json

I'm building a specification validator that is based on json format in a PHP environment. 
At some point, I considered creating a text editor which would help users directly edit and create their json.

In order to do that, I need the catch which errors are thrown when the json cannot be output (json_decode($myjson) returns NULL).

I've tried using both json_last_error() and json_last_error_msg() builtin functions but they neither provides the granularity I need. 
What I want is to actually catch which character (or at least which line) is preventing the json from being decoded so that I can highlight it in the editor.

I've read that PHP does not nativly handle this. Is there a lib that do? If not, how would you tackle that issue? Do I need to code my own json encoder/decoder? If so, would you use regex on the string to explode it into subsets of arrays before recomposing the final object? Any other idea (maybe JS natively handles json decoding errors better than PHP does? :)

Cheers,

Comment: What you're looking for is something similar to [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: Exactly, but preferably in PHP. I'll still play around with jsonlint (https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint for those who wonders where to find the lib).

Comment: Found a PHP integration here: https://github.com/Seldaek/jsonlint :)